# selecting html by id using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to select a section of html from a webpage

I use the code:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://archiveofourown.org/works/1758087?view_full_work=true").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all(id="children"):
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

to get this:

```
<div id="children" class="children module">
  <h3 class="heading">Works inspired by this one:</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/works/2219289">not an origin story</a> by <a rel="author" href="/users/eiirene/pseuds/eiirene">eiirene</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and then extract the number (2219289) and name (eiirene).

When I run the same code on url = "http://archiveofourown.org/works/225563?view_full_work=true" to try to select this:

```
<div id="children" class="children module">
  <h3 class="heading">Works inspired by this one:</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/works/240745">Cover-  Performance in A Leading Role by mad_lori</a> by <a rel="author" href="/users/blanketforyourshock/pseuds/blanketforyourshock">blanketforyourshock</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/works/341326">Movie still: To A Stranger</a> by <a rel="author" href="/users/RedOrchid/pseuds/RedOrchid">RedOrchid</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/works/787850">Future Yesterday</a> by <a rel="author" href="/users/ladymac111/pseuds/ladymac111">ladymac111</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It returns 'None'. If I use find_all it returns an empty list [].

Any ideas?

Comment: The web page with the second URL has adult content so doesn't render try adding the parameter to the querystring view_adult=true i.e. http://archiveofourown.org/works/225563?view_adult=true&view_full_work=true

Comment: Fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included both urls in a list and looped over them. Also I used the requests library for simplicity.

Code:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["http://archiveofourown.org/works/1758087?view_full_work=true", "http://archiveofourown.org/works/225563?view_full_work=true"]
for url in urls:
    print("***********************")
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    part = soup.find("div", id="children")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(part), 'html.parser')
    nums = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('/works/'))
    names = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('/users/'))
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        print(str(nums[i]['href']).split('/works/')[1] + " : " + names[i].text)
```

Output:

```
***********************
2219289 : eiirene
***********************
240745 : blanketforyourshock
341326 : RedOrchid
787850 : ladymac111
```